ECS container instance metrics in CloudWatch
In AWS ECS I have a cluster called demo-cluster which contains 2 services test-service-1 and test-service-2. Inside test-service-1 there are 4 tasks running task1, task2, task3 and task4. Inside task1 there are 2 containers test-container1 and test-container2. Now, in aws cloudwatch what metrices for test-container1 can I see and how?
I tried referring the aws documentation but seems like there is no clear explanation around this.

You would need to enable ECS Container Insights (at an added cost) in order to see individual container metrics in CloudWatch. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContainerInsights.html
